# Adding DIVs dynamically to table and showing with jQuery and partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem that I have looked in vain to try to resolve.  First, I have a page that presents some selections to the user to perform a search of data in the database.  This is acheived with an AJAX call and a partial view into an empty DIV on the page.  Inside of this partial view I am trying to add DIVs in the column for the ID of the list of items and set it to display:none.  Upon clicking the ID I want to send a request via AJAX to pull the details for that ID and then load that dynamically created DIV with another partial view.  Here is a sample of the page:

```
 //div with table of fields to enter selections for search

 <div>
    <input type="button" value="search" onclick="Search()" />
 <div>
 <div id="searchResults"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetData() {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: '@Url.Action("GetTours", "Tours")',
           data: $(".searchModel").serializeArray(),
           success: function(data) {
               $("#searchResults").html(data);
               $("#searchResults").show();
           }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

This works fine and I have no problem with it.  Inside the partial view of the serach results I am doing this:

```
 <div>
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Date</th>
          // more headers
       <tr>
       @if (Model != null)
       {
          foreach (var tour in Model.Tours)
          {
             <tr>
                <td>
                  <a onclick="showTour(@tour.id)">@tour.id</a>

                </td>
                <td>
                   @tour.date
                </td>
              <tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                  <div id="string.Format("div{0}, tour.id)"style="display:none"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
          }
     </table>
  </div>
```

And the JQ for the click event is:

```
   var lastId = 0;
   function showTour(id) {
      if (lastId === id) {
         $("#div" + lastId).hide();
      } else {
         lastId = id;
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '@Url.Action("Selected", "Tours")',
             data: ('tourId' : lastId },
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#div" + lastId).html(data);
                 $("#div" + lastId).show();
             }
        });
   }
```

When I debug I can see all the requests get to the controller, no problem, and the partial views are being returned to the pages.  I can see the entire partial view in the 'data' element upon success of the AJAX call but the DIV never opens up.  I expect it to open up right below the line but it does not.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This line doesn't look right: `<div id="string.Format("div{0}, tour.id)" `. Looks like it's missing Razor syntax.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, yes it is actually "@string.Format("div{0}, tour.id)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be impossible to achieve.  However, I was able to send the entire model, including all lists to the page, and construct an expanding/collapsing row under each table row to display details.